# PDFBox align numbers vice verca

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

Is it possible somehow to align numbers but in vice versa, or :
I don`t know what will be number but lets say that for the first i have 
2.12 then every new number will be on new row(let say that the second and third numbers are 312.33, 34.34) and want to be align like this :

```
  2.12

313.33

 34.34
```

is it possible ?

Comment: No pdfbox can't do that. Why don't you use  monospace font and String.format()?

Comment: pdfbox cannot do that out-of-the-box but you can of course implement a method to  do that based on PDFBox.

Comment: you can do that change the value of tx argument in newLineAtOffset(tx, ty) method

Comment: Well i found a solution it a simple one, separate the word(number) into symbols and i`m looking at what is the position of the cursor before and after printing the symbol, and adjust the cursor depending of the width of the printed symbol